# Gdal-Merge unknown error

Tags: raster, merge, gdal-merge

I am trying to merge 2 files, but the instruction gives this error:

"'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe0' in position 213: ordinal not in range(128) See log for more details"

what can it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a python coding error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20

As a workaround: avoid any non-ASCII chracters in Windows usernames, filenames, paths and folder names.

Comment: Thanks! Now I want to merge 2 raster files, but assigning the overlapped area to a specific one.

How could I do it?

Comment: Since this is not related to the encode error anymore, please open a new question for it.